# removing an element from hashmap<integer,object>

Tags: java

I have a hashmap of

```
   private final Map<Integer, GameSpecific> id_gameSpecifics = new HashMap<Integer, GameSpecific>();
```

and I want to remove an element from it using:

```
public void deleteGameSpecific(Integer specificId){

        GameSpecific gameSpecific =  id_gameSpecifics.get(specificId);
        if(gameSpecific !=null){
            id_gameSpecifics.remove(gameSpecific);
        }

}
```

I tried the above function but it doesn't remove the item from that hashmap.

Comment: Sorry for confustion

Comment: You need to remove it via the key (an `Integer`), not the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
public void deleteGameSpecific(Integer specificId){

    id_gameSpecifics.remove(specificId); //doesn't matter if previously contained

}
```

The argument for `Map.remove()` is the key of the item you want to remove (i.e. `specificId`), not the item itself.